# 'as adverb as' or 'adverb + as much as'?

Tags: comparison

I'm wondering in use of  'as adverb as' and 'adverb + as much as'.

**Which is grammatically valid** as well as **natural to use?**

> It is extremely hot as much as it was.
>
> It is hot as extremely as it was

What I want to say is the next sentence. (someone brought up this)

> It is extremely hot, just as hot as it was before.

If those sentences I made are both wrong, can you suggest alternatives additionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the basic structure right: **it is as hot as it was before**.

If you want to use an adverb to modify the adjective, it goes next to the adjective, just like it would anywhere else:  **It was extremely hot.  It is as extremely hot as it was before.**

Answer (score 0):

as + adjective/adverb + as

"...as extremely hot as..." doesn't sound like something a native English speaker would say.
Basically although 'extremely' is an adverb, it is an adverb of degree which modifies the adjective. Another example of an adverb of degree is 'very' and so we can't say 'as very bad as..' However other adverbs like, badly can be used as they don't modify an adjective. E.g. He didn't play as badly as last time.